# Got new router and raspi4 will not connect to wifi

Tags: pi-4

I have a 3d printer hooked to a raspi4 and octopi and everything has been working fine for about 4 months. I just got a new spectrum router and modem. Its still all the same cable internet just new equipment. I changed the network name and the password in the wpa_supplicant.conf file and now it won't connect to the wifi.  Have tried 2.4 and 5 GHZ modes.  Went back in and edited the name and password multiple times and still will not connect. I have no keyboard or monitor connected and can't ssh due to no wifi. Again this worked fine on the old router but not on the new one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you edit the file with?  Notepad on the PC puts life feed at the end of each line and FileEdit on the Mac can change quotes.   Did you set the WiFi country code? Can you edit the question and put your wpa_supplicant in using copy and paste into a code block and then use find/replace to hide your password.  Do not forget you can pop your Pi in via Ethernet and use ssh to test connection to the WiFi.

Comment: Ok, I hooed it up with a cable and everything works ok. I'll have to check the file again to look for mistakes in the ssid and password. It's printing right now so that will be tomorrow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more electronics than Pi.  I cannot use the 'question belong on another site' as that only lists Pi Meta!

Comment: OK, it's all my bad. Even after checking the network and password at least five times there was one lower case f in there that i never saw. Four hours for one letter!

Comment: Strange I did not vote to close this question but another one....

Comment: @Dean Please create an answer with the solution and mark it as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you were able to solve it with just reconfirming your WPA credentials. Sometimes you can spend hours debugging, only to find the solution was as simple as that!

Comment: +10, but you should give the questioner some time to learn to answer its own question.